# T-SQL numeric(x, y) equivalent data type in Access

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, type-conversion, ms-access-2010

I have a table definition (from SQL Server) which has columns like `abc numeric(22,6)` or `bce numeric(9,5)`, or `mnp numeric(20,10)`.

I have to keep those precisions. Which data type is equivalent in Access 2010?

I tried `Double` but it doesn't work for my target table (which has the data types from above).

I thought perhaps `Decimal` would work, but this also throws a conversion error when I export the data using SSIS.

Maybe I'm not setting this up correctly. **What would you use** for a `numeric(22,6)` in Access? `decimal (precision, scale, decimal places)`? I tried with `(22, 6, auto)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What would you use for a numeric(22,6) in Access?

`Decimal(22,6)` is definitely the corresponding field type in Access. I just used the

```
External Data > Import & Link > ODBC Database
```

feature in Access 2010 to import a SQL Server table like this

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NumericTest](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [numericcol] [numeric](22, 6) NULL,
    ...
```

and the resulting Access table did indeed have a `Decimal(22,6)` column ...

[image: TableDesign.png]

... so it *is* possible.

Comment: I wasn't sure if they corresponded. Thank you for the clear answer